# BottomSheetDialog - remove transparent space below

Tags: android

I have BottomSheetDialog in Android, but the bottom part (that overlays the navigation bar) is transparent, is there any way for me to make it white?

I've set the NavigationBar color of the activity to white and this seems to trigger the transparent region:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/white</item>
```

I don't think it matters, but I've set the style of the BottomSheetDialog to `RoundedBottomSheetDialog` in order to create the rounded corners:

```
<style name="RoundedBottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/bottomSheetStyleWrapper</item>
</style>

<style name="bottomSheetStyleWrapper" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this line inside of `RoundedBottomSheetDialog`:

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
```

See here for a project that implements this correctly:

https://github.com/gavingt/SunCalculator/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values-v27/styles.xml

And see here for the reference I used while creating the above project:

https://medium.com/halcyon-mobile/implementing-googles-refreshed-modal-bottom-sheet-4e76cb5de65b